# Assign key of an array element to a variable

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following piece of code and inside the function field_has_input(), I would like to assign the element's key to the errors[]

i.e. errors[]=$key instead of errors[]=$field

The function field_has_input($field) gets called from check_all_fields($_POST)

Hopefully someone can help out.

```
function field_has_input($field)
{
    global $errors;

    if(!isset($field) || empty($field))
    {
        $errors[]=$field;
    }
```

}

```
function check_all_fields($_POST)
{
     global $errors;
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $_POST[$key] . "<br />";
         field_has_input($_POST[$key]);

    }
    //exit;
    var_dump($errors);
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: It is currently the key's value that is being passed to your `field_has_input` function.  However that function will never add anything to the `$errors` array as it is only called for keys that actually exist in `$_POST`.  I am not really sure what you are attempting to do here.

Comment: @MikeBrant - you mean to say isset and empty only check for variables or keys and not values ?  And in the current case they happen to be actually checking for a value and so it won't work? Just trying to confirm if i did understand you correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you dispense with the `field_has_input()` function entirely, and just do the work inside the other loop. Otherwise, you would need to be passing the `$key`  into the inner function. In its current simplicity it is totally unnecessary and adds complexity.

```
function check_all_fields($_POST)
{
     global $errors;
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        // empty() calls isset() implicitly...
        if (empty($value)) {
          $errors[] = $key;
        }
    }
    //exit;
    var_dump($errors);
    return $errors;
}
```

Further, I would recommend not using the `global` errors, but instead passing it to the function. Because `$_POST` is a superglobal, it is unnecessary to pass it as a parameter to your function. Pass only `$errors` instead.

```
function check_all_fields($errors) {
  //  $_POST is already available here...
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
  {
    if (empty($value)) {
      $errors[] = $key;
    }
  }
  return $errors;
}
```

If you *must* use an inner function, such as if the actual work to be done in `field_has_input()` is more complex than just checking `empty()`, pass the `$key` and check `$_POST[$key]` inside the function

```
function field_has_input($key, $errors) {
  if (empty($_POST[$key])) {
    $errors[] = $key;
  }
}
```

Comment: "I would suggest you dispense with the field_has_input() function entirely" But your example code's still calling it from inside the other function?   I think I like your approach(3rd piece of code) of passing $key and then checking $_POST[$key]... But can you just clarify on the first 2 examples...maybe that's another appproach I could learn about...

Comment: @user481913 Copy/paste failure... Sorry fixed.

Comment: +1 Thanks for all the different approaches  and pointing out a better way to do this... I'm trying out both approaches and hopefully if i have any other clarifications, you could help me out with them as well...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an array of values consisting of the $_POST keys that are empty, you can do that with just one line:

```
$errors = array_keys( array_diff_key( $_POST, array_filter($_POST) ) );
```

1. [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will remove false, null or empty string values
2. [array_diff_key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) will compare the original full post array to the filtered version and return only the keys that have been filtered.
3. [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will create an array of values using the array keys of the given array

Example, if:

```
$arr = array (
     'name'     => 'Bob'
    ,'company'  => ''
    ,'state'    => 'CA'
    ,'phone'    => '' 
);

$errors = array_keys( array_diff_key( $arr, array_filter($arr) ) );
var_dump($errors);

// output:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "company"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "phone"
}
```